# How to specify databases to be replicated in MongoDB replicasets?

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to MongoDB.

I know that MongoDB can replicate the nodes.

Is there a way to choose specific databases to be replicated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a MongoDB replica set, the entire node is replicated between all members of the replica set.  In this way you don't pick a specific database to replicate, rather all databases on the primary node are replicated to all the secondary nodes.

Answer (score 3):

No, in a replica set, every node contains the exact same data as the other nodes, so that at any point a secondary can step up and be the primary seamlessly.  There is no way to pick and choose what databases are included, nor would there be any way to make that work with the intention of using them for redundancy.